How to add a second project in an AWS Lambda AOT .NET 8 project solution?
I am using the latest .NET 8 with the AWS Lambda templates in Visual Studio 2022 to create and deploy an AOT (Ahead of Time) compilation option. When I only have that single project, and have Docker for Windows running, it gets compiled and deployed perfectly. Runs just fine.
However, when I add a second project to the same solution (just a .NET class-library), the Docker build that is run as part of the deployment fails!
Example output is below. The second project is in a different folder (obviously), It seems like the Docker build doesn't copy/find the second project?
Any idea on how to solve this?
Executing publish command
Starting container for native AOT build using build image: public.ecr.aws/sam/build-dotnet8:latest-x86_64.
... invoking 'docker run --name tempLambdaBuildContainer-xxxx --rm --volume "D:\FirstFolder\LambdaLocat1":/tmp/source/ -i public.ecr.aws/sam/build-dotnet8:latest-x86_64 dotnet publish "/tmp/source/" --output "/tmp/source\bin\Release\net8.0\publish" --configuration "Release" --framework "net8.0" --self-contained true /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true --runtime linux-x64 /p:StripSymbols=true' from directory D:\FirstFolder\LambdaLocat1
... docker run: MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
... docker run: /var/lang/bin/sdk/8.0.204/NuGet.targets(414,5):
 error MSB3202: The project file "/tmp/SecondFolder/LambdaCommon.csproj" was not found. [/tmp/source/LambdaLocat1.sln]
ERROR: Container build returned 1

I tried different .NET project types (all .NET 8) for the 2nd project, didn't help.
I deleted the whole primary (Lambda) solution/project and created a new one, didn't help.
